# Default option for LookupRows when ROWCOUNT = 0

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am trying to set a default value if a subscriber does not have a store allocated to them within our send data extension. The below works for when the store matches a value with my Store_Details data extension, however, when a customer's details contain something different like a new store name which is not listed is the Store_Details data extension or contains a blank value (more common) I want to display the Head Office​​​​​​​ details from my Store_Details data extension​​​​​​​. I've tried a couple of ways to get the two to work without success. Any ideas welcomed!

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */

%%[
/* Use below when a subscriber is not registered to a store */

var @Store, @HeaderImage, @FooterLogo, @StoreName, @OpeningHours, @OpeningDays, @Address, @Phone, @Email

SET @store = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", Store)

%%[
if ROWCOUNT(@store) == 0 then
]%%

SET @store = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", 'Head Office')
.
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)
SET @Store = Field(@row, "Store_label")
SET @HeaderImage = Field(@row, "HeaderImage_label")
SET @FooterLogo = Field(@row, "FooterLogo_label")
SET @StoreName = Field(@row, "StoreName_label") 
SET @OpeningHours = Field(@row, "OpeningHours_label")
SET @OpeningDays = Field(@row, "OpeningDays_label")
SET @Address = Field(@row, "Address_label")
SET @Phone = Field(@row, "Phone_label")
SET @Email = Field(@row, "Email_label")

%%[
else

/* Set email details for each store */
]%%

  %%[

SET @store = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", Store)
.
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)
SET @Store = Field(@row, "Store_label")
SET @HeaderImage = Field(@row, "HeaderImage_label")
SET @FooterLogo = Field(@row, "FooterLogo_label")
SET @StoreName = Field(@row, "StoreName_label") 
SET @OpeningHours = Field(@row, "OpeningHours_label")
SET @OpeningDays = Field(@row, "OpeningDays_label")
SET @Address = Field(@row, "Address_label")
SET @Phone = Field(@row, "Phone_label")
SET @Email = Field(@row, "Email_label")

    ]%%

%%[
endif
]%%

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Bevan :)

First of all, I think you don't have to use the opening and closing tags  of Ampscript - `%%[` `]%%` - in the middle parts of the code. Furthermore, I think the problem is about the rowset.

Your rowset is `@store` but you use `@rowset` instead of that.

Hence, if you change `SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)` with `SET @row = Row(@store, 1)`, it will be fixed.

At the end, the code is:

```
%%[
/* Use below when a subscriber is not registered to a store */

var @Store, @HeaderImage, @FooterLogo, @StoreName, @OpeningHours, @OpeningDays, @Address, @Phone, @Email

SET @store = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", 'Store')
SET @row = Row(@store, 1)
SET @store_label = Field(@row, "Store_label")

IF ROWCOUNT(@store) == 0 OR EMPTY(@store_label) THEN /* Also control if it is empty */

SET @store = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", 'Head Office')

ENDIF

SET @row = Row(@store, 1)
SET @Store = Field(@row, "Store_label")
SET @HeaderImage = Field(@row, "HeaderImage_label")
SET @FooterLogo = Field(@row, "FooterLogo_label")
SET @StoreName = Field(@row, "StoreName_label") 
SET @OpeningHours = Field(@row, "OpeningHours_label")
SET @OpeningDays = Field(@row, "OpeningDays_label")
SET @Address = Field(@row, "Address_label")
SET @Phone = Field(@row, "Phone_label")
SET @Email = Field(@row, "Email_label")

]%%
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the above but was still having an issue when the store name did not correspond exactly to one from our store data extension.

Answer (score 0):

%%[/* AMPScript Email Content initialization  */

SET @Debug = false

/*DATA EXTENSIONS*/

SET @Store_Details = 'Store_Details'

/*Content fields*/

SET @Store_label = "Store"
SET @HeaderImage_label = "HeaderImage"
SET @FooterLogo_label = "FooterLogo"
SET @StoreName_label = "StoreName"
SET @OpeningHours_label = "OpeningHours"
SET @OpeningDays_label = "OpeningDays"
SET @Address_label = "Address"
SET @Phone_label = "Phone"
SET @Email_label = "Email"

/*ROWS*/

SET @EmailLookUpRow = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", Store)

SET @EmailRowCountLookUp = rowcount(@EmailLookUpRow)

IF @EmailRowCountLookUp ==0 THEN

SET @Estate = 'Head Office'

SET @EmailLookUpRow = LookupRows("Store_Details","Store_label", 'Head Office')

ENDIF

SET @EmailRowCountLookUp = rowcount(@EmailLookUpRow)

IF @EmailRowCountLookUp ==0 THEN

RaiseError("Email content data extension does not contain store content", true)

ELSE

SET @Row = Row(@EmailLookUpRow,1)

/*Expose values to variables*/

SET @Store = Field(@row, "Store_label")
SET @HeaderImage = Field(@row, "HeaderImage_label")
SET @FooterLogo = Field(@row, "FooterLogo_label")
SET @StoreName = Field(@row, "StoreName_label") 
SET @OpeningHours = Field(@row, "OpeningHours_label")
SET @OpeningDays = Field(@row, "OpeningDays_label")
SET @Address = Field(@row, "Address_label")
SET @Phone = Field(@row, "Phone_label")
SET @Email = Field(@row, "Email_label")

ENDIF

//

]%%